# How To Interrupt/Stop a Working Thread (not current thread) In Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Hello EveryOne**

i want to  stop a working thread not current one

i don't want this way

```
Thread. currentThread().interrupt()
```

because it is only works with current thread in same method block

and i want to block any thread by its name

> note:

this way will not work because my thread is not a current thread and `interrupt()` method only works for current as i mentioned

```
Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

//Iterate over set to find yours
for(Thread thread : setOfThread){
    if(thread.getId()==yourThread.getId()){
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

> the following is my code

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

and

```
@Async("threadPoolExecutor")
public void MyTask(){
    System.out.println("Currently Executing thread name - " + 
    Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("User created with thread pool executor");
}
```

so when i execute MyTask() it takes a name

**My Question** is that i want to stop this process by its name after x of time and only when i request the stop() method as long as the thread still working

> e.g.

```
@GetMapping(value="/stopThreadByName/{threadname}")
public String stop(@PathVariable("threadname") String name) {
    //some code to stop the thread by its name
}
```

Comment: Then call `interrupt()` on the `Thread` you want to interrupt instead of the current thread. You will obviously need to keep a reference to that thread, since getting all the threads and finding by id is a pretty poor way to go about it.

Comment: Can you show what threads you want to stop specifically? Any running tasks?

Comment: *this way will not work because my thread is not a current thread and interrupt() method only works for current as i mentioned* - this isn't mentioned in the javadocs and in fact is [the correct way to stop a thread which you have no control on](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). Where did you read `interrupt()` works only on current thread?

Comment: i use a spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and i want to stop the outgoing thread of it

Comment: please see the question again , i have updated it

Answer (score 1):

You may need to maintain a map for the thread name and the Future reference of the Task.

```
public static Map<String, Future> futureMap = new HashMap<String, Future>();

@Async("threadPoolExecutor")
public Future<String> MyTask(String name){
    ...
    Future<String> obj = new AsyncResult<String>("something");
    futureMap.put(name, obj);
    return obj;
}


futureMap.put(taskName, executor.submit(task));
```

And when you invoke stop,

```
@GetMapping(value="/stopThreadByName/{threadname}")
public String stop(@PathVariable("threadname") String name) {
    //some code to stop the thread by its name
    Future taskNeedsToBeStop = futureMap.get("taskNeedsToBeStop");
    taskNeedsToBeStop.cancel(true);
}
```

Here,

```
<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)
```

Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns a Future representing the pending results of the task. The Future's get method will return the task's result upon successful completion.
If you would like to immediately block waiting for a task, you can use constructions of the form `result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();`

```
boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when `cancel` is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
After this method returns, subsequent calls to `isDone()` will always return true. Subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` will always return true if this method returned true.

Comment: i think your answer may be good but i cant implement it in my code , could you explain it detailed please because i am still new in java

Comment: Create a static map and whenever you invoke method i.e. executor.submit at the time get that future object and add in the map along with the thread name.

Comment: i added the thread name before the return of my threadpooltaskexecutor method and couldn't exactly what to add in the future object of Map?could you add a code involve that implementation based on my code?

Comment: Modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to stop the task, not the actual thread. The whole point of a threadpool is to reuse threads for multiple tasks without having to start a new thread for every task.

To do that, you must write the task in a way such that it can be stopped without exceptions, for example by checking for a flag in multiple places in your code.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Boolean> stopped;

@Async("threadPoolExecutor")
public void MyTask(){
   doStep1();
   if(stopped.remove(taskName, true)) return;
   while(...){
     doStepN();
     if(stopped.remove(taskName, true)) return;
   }
}

public String stop(@PathVariable("taskName") String taskName) {
    stopped.put(taskName, true);
}
```

Comment: for what the doStep1() and doStepN() refer to?and what is the stopped variable function ?

Comment: and what about resuming the task ?